# SQL - Find rows starting with the same characters

Tags: sql, database, oracle

I have an oracle database with a table containing data that may start with the same prefix and would like to find rows that the 5 digit prefix is duplicated somewhere in the table.
For Example:

```
Table1 
---------------
12345-brsd
12345-wbgb
12345-ydad
34573-diwe
75234-daie
72456-woei
72456-wdgq
```

I want to return only the ones that the first 5 digits are duplicate, so out of this sample:

```
12345-brsd
12345-wbgb
12345-ydad
72456-woei
72456-wdgq
```

Comment: Use `GROUP BY` to group the rows with the same prefix together and extract a single row for each, and `HAVING count(*) > 1` to find the dupes.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this using analytic functions:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*, count(*) over (partition by substr(column, 1, 5)) as cnt
      from table t
     ) t
where cnt > 1
order by column1;
```